# Медленная работа редактора кода Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Обновил студию с 1.3 до 1.4 после перезагрузки редактор кода жутко тормозит, невозможно нормально писать. Также лагает курсор выделения элементов меню. 
Скорость сборки осталась прежней. Посоветуйте как решить проблему с тормозами редактора.

Comment: Какая операционная система и железо?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема решилась изменением idea.properties. Необходимо добавить:

```
sun.java2d.d3d=false
```

вот обсуждение данной проблемы:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191229